# Loading user-control on click event

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a single asp  page on that i have different navigation button. i want to register the user control on link button click and display that user-control in div,which is i mention in my code.here is my code.i am stuck over here.user-control contain some code and user-control are in update-panel any help will be appreciated.
`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function ShowInfo() {
            $('#common').show();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <ul class="acc-menu" id="sidebar">
            <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Settings</span> <span class="badge badge-indigo">5</span></a>
                <ul class='acc-menu'>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="ShowInfo();">Account Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vehicle Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="ShowInfo();">Driver Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub User Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Admin Tools</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="common" style="height: 100%; display: none;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this ASP.NET project. It is a complete sample project on how to add user controls to a page dynamically.

http://snippets.surfthru.com/post/Dynamically-Adding-User-Controls-to-an-ASPX-page